# error in select(): invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Here is my server code, dont know how i got

```
failed to select : Invalid argument
```

its work fine on my mac, but not on linux. 
can someone tell me where i did wrong ?

Im just new begynniner in c programming.

server.c

```
int server(int port){

int request_sd, newfd;
socklen_t clientaddrlen; 
fd_set masterList;
fd_set readFd;


int bind_adress = 0, listen_connect = 0;
int fd_max;
int select_client, i; 
struct sockaddr_in server_adr;
struct sockaddr_in client_adr;

if (!getcwd(root_path, PATH_LEN))
{
    perror("set path");
}


request_sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

if (request_sd < 0)
{
    perror("failed: ");
    return -1;
}else printf("create new socket i complete:  %d\n", request_sd);

memset(&server_adr, 0 , sizeof (struct sockaddr_in));

server_adr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_adr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_adr.sin_port = htons(port);



int activate = 1;
if (setsockopt(request_sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &activate, sizeof(int)) == -1)
{
    perror("setsockopt: ");
    return -1;
}

bind_adress = bind(request_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_adr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
if (bind_adress < 0 )
{
    perror("failed to bind : ");
    return -1;
}

listen_connect = listen(request_sd, 10);
if (listen_connect <0)
{
    perror("failed to listen : ");
    return -1;
}

printf("\nListening for connections on port: %d\n\n", port);

fflush(stdout);
FD_ZERO(&masterList);
FD_ZERO(&readFd);
FD_SET(request_sd, &masterList);

fd_max = request_sd;
while(1){


    readFd = masterList;
    if((select_client = select(fd_max+1, &readFd, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0){
        perror("FAILED TO SELECT");
    }

    for ( i = 0; i <= fd_max; i++)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(i,&readFd))
        {
            if(i == request_sd)
            {
                newfd = accept(request_sd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_adr, 
                    (socklen_t *) &clientaddrlen);
                if (newfd == -1 )
                {
                    perror("failed to accept :");
                    return -1;
                }
                FD_SET(newfd, &masterList);
                if (newfd > fd_max)
                {
                    fd_max = newfd;
                }
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings on `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. What do you get?

Comment: Filtjener.c:88:5: warning: (this will be reported only once per input file)
Filtjener.c: In function 'ls_handler':
Filtjener.c:106: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
Filtjener.c:103: warning: unused parameter 'package'
Filtjener.c: In function 'cd_handler':
Filtjener.c:127: warning: unused parameter 'package'
Filtjener.c: In function 'info_handler':
Filtjener.c:200: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code

Comment: Filtjener.c: In function 'cat_handler':
Filtjener.c:250: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
Filtjener.c:230: warning: unused parameter 'currentPath'
Filtjener.c: In function 'action':
Filtjener.c:319: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
Filtjener.c: In function 'server':
Filtjener.c:408: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
Filtjener.c:463: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code

Comment: Fix those warnings. Also you might like to add such info to your question as update.

Comment: but it have nothing to do with the server. When i try to connect from client on linux, i get failed to connect :  Invalid argument

Comment: Seems correct, so the issue might due from something that went wrong before reaching this point, most propably some memory corruption. See what is shown when running the server using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.og).

Comment: Does your Linux box have IPV6 enabled? Are the values of the different descriptors OK (print them out for debugging)?

Comment: Inaccurate title. -1

Answer (score 2):

Since `select()` is complaining about a bad parameter, and you are passing only two parameters to it, that means either `fd_max` is invalid or `readFd` is invalid. The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) states:

> EINVAL 
>   **nfds is negative** or the value contained within timeout is invalid.

Since you are not using the `timeout` parameter, look at your `fd_max` variable, make sure you are not overflowing it.

Aside from that, you should use `fd_copy()` instead of `readFd = masterList` on platforms that support it.

```
 FD_COPY(&masterList, &readFd);
```

A better option is to use [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [`epoll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) instead of `select()`.  It is easier to manage, and it tells you the exact socket(s) that satisfied the wait so you don't have to hunt for them.